# Reputation area for Acheivements appears broken with stale data

Tags: bug, reputation, achievements-dialog, caching

The reputation piece of the Achievements menu appears to be broken (stale data). I've earned some and it has not populated in the menu. I see stuff for UTC yesterday and nothing from UTC today (about 17:00).

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: [You should blame caching.](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/)

Comment: Unless it's, like, a day or two stale... I'd just assume caching for most stale data issues around here.

Comment: Same here. Not only the isn't the green notification showing, but when clicking on the rep icon, recent (~1 hour ago) rep gains aren't showing

Comment: @Kendra its only showing me "yesterday"

Comment: @DanielA.White Worth mentioning in the question, then. Pretty important for determining if something is indeed wrong: Time of the last result showing, time(s) of what isn't showing but should be... Cause if it's cached from yesterday, but you got something a couple hours ago that still hasn't shown up... Starting to look less like caching.

Comment: The last things I see are ~5h ago. I'm definitely missing things from ~3h ago. Seems it crashed somewhere inbetween.